# read specified range of lines from a file

Tags: linux, files, sed

I have i file that contains 100000 line
how i can get the lines from line# 5555 to line# 7777 under linux.

Thanks for all.

Comment: @ibrahim, consider accepting Kyle's answer (by ticking the green checkmark on the left) if it helped you

Comment: you may precise if you want to use sed or if other tools are OK.

Comment: A little bit of research throws at least http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix

Answer (score 22):

```
sed '5555,7777!d' <filename>
```

This will print lines 5555-7777 of the file inclusively.

Dennis Posted the following which I agree should be faster:

`sed '5555,7777p; 7778q' filename`

The following evidence that it should be faster:

```
$ n=1
$ while [[ n -le 100000 ]]; do echo $n >> sedtest2; n=$((n + 1)); done
$ strace -e trace=read -o sed1 sed '5555,7777!d' sedtest2
$ strace -e trace=read -o sed2 sed '5555,7777p; 7778q' sedtest2
$ wc -l sed1
149 sed1
$ wc -l sed2
14 sed1
```

---

In Bash only (for fun):

```
n=1
while read line; do 
    if [[ ($n -ge 5555) && ($n -le 7777)  ]]; then 
        echo $line
    elif [[ $n -gt 7777 ]]; then
        break
    fi 
    n=$(( $n + 1 ))
done < file
```

Comment: I think your `$n -gt 3` should be 7777 perhaps? Also, you can do `if (( n >= 5555 ))` for more "natural" looking numeric comparison operators (and the ability to leave off the dollar sign). And you can do `((n++))`.

Answer (score 16):

Quitting when you're done can speed things up:

```
sed -n '5555,7777p; 7778q' input_file
```

Comment: +1 , should be faster, updated my post to show why.

Answer (score 7):

Either of these should work;

- sed -n '*startnumber*,*endnumber*p'
- awk 'NR>=*startnumber*&&NR<=*endnumber*' file

Great question by the way ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the sed option did not work on a mysqldump file, I'm guessing due to handling of quoted line feeds or multibyte characters. head and tail slice it using the same line numbers as grep which was what I needed. To get lines $j through $k, you need:

```
x=$(( $k - $j + 1 ))
tail -n +$j filename | head -${x}
```