# How to display certain lines from a text file in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, sed, tail

I guess everyone knows the useful Linux cmd line utilities `head` and `tail`. `head` allows you to print the first X lines of a file, `tail` does the same but prints the end of the file. What is a good command to print the middle of a file? something like `middle --start 10000000 --count 20` (print the 10’000’000th till th 10’000’010th lines).

I'm looking for something that will deal with large files efficiently. I tried `tail -n 10000000 | head 10` and it's horrifically slow.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/101900/read-specified-range-of-lines-from-a-file

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
sed -n '10000000,10000020p' filename
```

You might be able to speed that up a little like this:

```
sed -n '10000000,10000020p; 10000021q' filename
```

In those commands, the option `-n` causes `sed` to "suppress automatic printing of pattern space". The `p` command "print[s] the current pattern space" and the `q` command "Immediately quit[s] the sed script without processing any more input..." The quotes are from the [`sed` `man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).

By the way, your command

```
tail -n 10000000 filename | head -n 10
```

starts at the ten millionth line from the *end* of the file, while your "middle" command would seem to start at the ten millionth from the *beginning* which would be equivalent to:

```
head -n 10000010 filename | tail -n 10
```

The problem is that for unsorted files with variable length lines any process is going to have to go through the file counting newlines. There's no way to shortcut that.

If, however, the file is sorted (a log file with timestamps, for example) or has fixed length lines, then you can seek into the file based on a byte position. In the log file example, you could do a binary search for a range of times as my Python script [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/101744/fast-extraction-of-a-time-range-from-syslog-logfile/102531#102531)* does. In the case of the fixed record length file, it's really easy. You just seek `linelength * linecount` characters into the file.

<sup>* I keep meaning to post yet another update to that script. Maybe I'll get around to it one of these days.</sup>

Comment: Here is a `sed` version of Charles' `middle` function: `middle() { local s=$1 c=$2; shift 2; sed -n "$s,$(($s + $c -1))p; $(($s + $c))q" "$@"; }`. It will handle multiple file arguments, filenames with spaces, etc. Multiple files are processed together as if they had been catted in the same way that `sed` normally does (so middle 1000 100 file1 file2 would span across the end of the first file to the beginning of the second one if the first one has fewer than 1100 lines).

Comment: The function in my previous comment can be called with a filename parameter: `middle startline count filename` or multiple filenames: `middle startline count file1 file2 file3` or with redirection: `middle startline count < filename` or in a pipe: `some_command | `middle startline count` or `cat file* | middle startline count`

Comment: Shouldn't the ` in your sed command be a '? I can't get it to work with the backtick but it works fine with the single quote.

Comment: @beanland: Yes, it's a typo. I've fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: `tail -n 10000` print the last 10000 lines. use `tail -n +10000` to start print at 10000th line.

Comment: FYI,
print from 10th line to the end : `sed -n '10,$p'`

Comment: Some more explanation would be nice. E.g. what is the "p", what is the "q" for at the end of the line numbers?

Comment: @kev: I added some explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 39):

I found out the following use of `sed`

```
sed -n '10000000,+20p'  filename
```

Hope it's useful to someone!

Comment: Good to know that there is an alternative to the last line argument proposed by Dennis: a line count as second `sed -n` argument which makes it quite readable.

Comment: An example usage: `extract_lines(){sed -n "$1,+$2p" <file>}` which writes to stdout.

Answer (score 7):

This is my first time posting here!  Anyway, this one is easy.  Let's say you want to pull line 8872 from your file called file.txt.  Here is how you do it:

cat -n file.txt | grep '^ *8872'

Now the question is to find 20 lines after this.  To accomplish this you do

cat -n file.txt | grep -A 20 '^ *8872'

For lines around or before see the -B and -C flags in the grep manual.

Comment: While that is technically correct and an interesting way to do it on a reasonably-sized file, I'm curious about its efficacy when working with files of the size the poster is asking about.

Comment: Multiple lines: cat -n file.txt | grep "^\s\+\(10\|20\|30\)\s\+"

Comment: `cat -n file.txt | grep '^ *1'` yield all the lines that have 1 on their right side. How to output line 1 with this technique? I know I can head -n 1....but how to use grep?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to get the particular range of lines

```
awk 'NR < 1220974{next}1;NR==1513793{exit}' debug.log | tee -a test.log
```

Here debug.log is my file which consists of a lacks of lines and i used to print the lines from 1220974 line number to 1513793 to a file test.log.
hope it ll helpful for capturing the range of lines.

Comment: The same answer as https://serverfault.com/a/641252/140016. Downvoted.

Comment: It is not the same answer. This should be faster for large files as it actually aborts after printing the last line instead of continuing scanning through the file.

Answer (score 2):

Perl is king:

```
perl -ne 'print if ($. == 10000000 .. $. == 10000020)' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Dennis' sed answer is the way to go.  But using just head & tail, under bash:

```
middle () { head -n $[ $1 + $2 ] | tail -n $2; }
```

This scans the first $1+$2 lines twice, so is much worse than Dennis' answer.  But you don't need to remember all those sed letters to use it....

Comment: Using `$[...]` is deprecated, at least in Bash. Also, you're missing a file parameter.

Comment: @Dennis: No missing parameter: you're meant to use this on stdin, as per `middle 10 10 < /var/log/auth.log`.

Answer (score 1):

A ruby oneliner version.

```
ruby -pe 'next unless $. > 10000000 && $. < 10000020' < filename.txt
```

It can be useful to somebody. 
The solutions with 'sed' provided by Dennis and Dox is very nice, even because it seems faster.

Answer (score 0):

For instance this awk will print lines between 20 and 40

> awk '{if ((NR > 20) && (NR < 40)) print $0}' /etc/passwd

Answer (score 0):

If you know the line numebrs, say you want to get line 1, 3 and 5 from a file, say /etc/passwd:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){if(++$l~~[1,3,5]){print}}' < /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'nl'.

```
nl filename | grep <line_num>
```

Comment: This is not good : if you request line 42, you will get all the lines which contain that number.